# How can VLC identify a CD in CDDB but ripperx can't?

Tags: cddb

I have a niche CD (ABRSM Exam Pieces for Grade 4 Violin) which VLC obtains all the track titles for from CDDB, but RipperX doesn't like - it gives an Error 23 CD not found in database pop-up.

I've tested Ripper X with another CD just to make sure it's ok, and it is. It's v 2.8.0 in case that's important. It's configured by default to use:

```
gnudb.gnudb.org/~cddb/cddb.cgi
```

I've tried to get Ripper X to accept other CDDB databases like the one VLC uses:

```
freedb.freedb.org
```

but then I get the error 20: unable to connect. Could be the URL, could be the wrong protocol, I don't know :(

Comment: The FAQ on sourceforge may be helpful? https://ripperx.sourceforge.net/faq.html

Comment: us.cddb.com/~cddb/cddb.cgi port 80 http gives error 20, and us.cddb.com gives error 22.

Comment: you should ask the maintainer but most likely it is the URL encoding.

Comment: the url encoding? you mean the maintainer of ripperx, vlc, or gnudb?

Answer (score 1):

I think I can answer my own question.

Not being able to get ripperx to use the same CDDB URL as VLC turns out to be a red herring.

VLC was not getting the track listing from CDDB - it was reading it from the CD. In 35 years of using CDs I never knew that info could actually be read from the CD.

I worked this out because I gave up on Ripper X and installed RhythmBox, which told me immediately that the CD couldn't be found in CDDB but still listed all the tracks with names and titles. Epiphanaic.